# Create a new order

Tags: commerce, rules

I am working with [Drupal commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) and I want to create a new order with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, when the *Completing checkout process* event is fired.

The second order should have all the same commerce line items the first order has.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can do the following (not entirely sure though)

Create a rule that triggers on Checkout completion and execute custom php code.

**How it works:**
On the event *Completing the checkout process* the order that is involved in this checkout process is available through the variable *$commerce_order*. Then we assign this order to a new variable and use it in the code provided by the function referenced below. We save the uid and profile_id from the order we want to clone so we can set the user and the billing information on the clone.

Import code of rule

```
{ "rules_clone_order" : {
    "LABEL" : "Clone order",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "custom" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "php", "rules", "commerce_checkout" ],
    "ON" : { "commerce_checkout_complete" : [] },
    "DO" : [
      { "php_eval" : { "code" : "$previous_order = $commerce_order;\r\n$uid = $previous_order-\u003Euid;\r\n$profile_id = $previous_order-\u003Ecommerce_customer_billing[LANGUAGE_NONE][0][\u0027profile_id\u0027];\r\n\r\nforeach (commerce_order_load_multiple(array(), array(\u0027status\u0027 =\u003E \u0027pending\u0027), TRUE) as $previous_order) {\r\n  $product_ids = array();\r\n  foreach (entity_metadata_wrapper(\u0027commerce_order\u0027, $previous_order)-\u003Ecommerce_line_items as $delta =\u003E $line_item_wrapper) {\r\n    if (in_array($line_item_wrapper-\u003Etype-\u003Evalue(), commerce_product_line_item_types())) {\r\n      $product_ids[] = $line_item_wrapper-\u003Ecommerce_product-\u003Eraw();\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}\r\n\r\n    $order = commerce_order_new ( $uid , \u0027pending\u0027 );\r\n    \/\/ Save the order so its ID is assigned.\r\n    commerce_order_save ( $order );\r\n\r\n    $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper ( \u0027commerce_order\u0027 , $order );\r\n\r\n    \/\/add products to order by ids array\r\n    foreach ( $product_ids as $product_id ) {\r\n        $product = commerce_product_load ( $product_id );\r\n\r\n        \/\/ Create a line item with quantity 1 and this product.\r\n        $line_item = commerce_product_line_item_new ( $product , 1 , $order-\u003Eorder_id );\r\n\r\n        \/\/ Save the line item to get its ID.\r\n        commerce_line_item_save ( $line_item );\r\n\r\n        \/\/ Add the line item to the order using the wrapper.\r\n        $order_wrapper-\u003Ecommerce_line_items[ ] = $line_item;\r\n    }\r\n\r\n\r\n    $profile_object = array ( \r\n        \u0027und\u0027 =\u003E array ( array ( \u0027profile_id\u0027 =\u003E $profile_id , ) , ) , ); \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    $order-\u003Ecommerce_customer_billing = $profile_object;\r\n\r\n    \/\/ Save the order.\r\n    commerce_order_save ( $order );" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Credits**:
The code to save an order comes from this post:   https://drupalcommerce.org/comment/3491#comment-3491

Comment: I still have an issue if you could help me again !

Comment: Great, good to hear :)

Comment: I just have another question , shall I tell you that here , or post another question ?

Comment: Better to post another question I guess :)

Comment: Already done , I will be very very pleased if you could help me in this issue , you will save my life if you do : Link : http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/229093/create-many-order-using-drupal-rules . Thank you